# Tag for code that loads code dynamically at runtime

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

I think we could use a tag for questions about loading code at runtime.  Ideally, it would apply to all programming languages.  Some examples of questions that such a tag could apply to:

#### Bash

- [Function autoloading in bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58485/9357)

#### Java

- [Generated code proxy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/20470/9357)

#### JavaScript

- [Loading JavaScript files asynchronously](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6110/9357)
- [JavaScript modules loading with eval()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/25901/9357)

#### PHP

- [Just require a file, or check if_readable first?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/68758/9357)
- [PHP Autoloader Library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4/9357)
- [Simple autoloader, but trying to make it psr-compliat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60141/9357)

#### Python

- [Load modules conditionally Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/24349/9357)
- [Scanning a directory for plugins and loading them](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59715/9357)

#### Ruby

- [Loading 'Plugins' in Ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/29998/9357)
- [Return path to rubygems.rb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48200/9357)

There is an existing [modules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules) tag, but it doesn't quite fit: in some languages, they are closer to the idea of a namespace.  [plugin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) is also relevant, but has a connotation that the code is a user-swappable component.

Any idea what to call this tag?

Comment: [tag:late-binding]?

Comment: @Mat'sMug "Late binding" is too obscure. It can apply to code that is not dynamically loaded.

Comment: [tag:Eval] appears to be the commonly used term for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not state the obvious??

[dynamic-loading](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-loading) all the way! The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) states:

> Dynamic loading is a mechanism by which a computer program can, at run time, load a library (or other binary) into memory, retrieve the addresses of functions and variables contained in the library, execute those functions or access those variables, and unload the library from memory.

While this tag may be associated with java classloading and windows dll's it's exactly describing what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

I feel obliged to suggest [monkey-patch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-patch) ([From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)):

> A monkey patch is a way for a program to extend or modify supporting system software locally (affecting only the running instance of the program).

Bazinga!

Comment: Monkey patching usually refers to adding or altering functions in an already loaded library or class. Not all dynamic code loading is so underhanded.